# HP Officejet Pro 8000 making scary sounds after clearing a printer jam

Tags: printer, paper

I just cleared a pretty bad printer jam from my HP Officejet Pro 8000 wireless. After, it spent about 30-40 mins doing seemingly random spinning of its various innards before spitting out what seemed to be the last of the piece of paper it shredded.

Now it is back to printing, but it makes a very terrible sounding crunching noise when it starts feeding the paper. Additionally, the top of the paper is now slightly damaged from feeding, and the print itself appears askew.

Is there a way to tell what the problem is? Does it seem like maybe there's still a piece of paper stuck inside? Is there a way to fix this without paying for a repairman?

Comment: Depending on the price of the thing, it may be time to get a new one or get it repaired. There's no telling what's broken or misaligned.

Comment: Sounds like a misaligned or busted gear.  Time for a repair man.

Answer (score 0):

**It needs to be repaired.**

If you want to repair it by yourself then here's [HP OfficeJet 8000 Service Manual](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiF8aSY5a7KAhXCiRoKHXDQCA0QFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hp.com%2Fctg%2FManual%2Fc01659070.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEy1zX4sRbOzvcl7wLaZepUqvet8g&sig2=x3A1hmP-ARYCCi4_zOQReQ) .